# Horizontal Scrolling collection View issue

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to scroll horizontally to a collectionView when I call a function and am receiving the error 'none' is unavailable: use [] to construct an empty option set - not sure what is wrong here...Thanks in advance!

```
  func handleSearch() {
        scrollToMenuIndex(menuIndex: 2)
    }

    func scrollToMenuIndex(menuIndex: Int) {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: menuIndex, section: 0)
        collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .none, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Read the documentation for `UICollectionViewScrollPosition`. Note the lack of `none` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a position where the item should be scrolled to. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewscrollposition) for `UICollectionViewScrollPosition` for possible values. In the meantime you could use this:

```
collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
```